How can I find the ID of a site on Google News even if it's no longer indexed?
I'm looking for a way to find the identifier of a particular site like TheJournal.net on Google News, example: /publications/CAAqHggKIhhDQklTREFnTWFnZ0tCbU5oY1M1
Do you think I can correlate a domain name URL with its publication identifier on Google News?
The aim is to find sites that are on Google News (with a source) but are no longer indexed or not indexed at all.
Thank you very much,
I tried using other Google tools to find this string.
